# Can't access JPG, nor copy, nor open, nor change permissions

Tags: windows-xp, permissions, jpeg

A few JPGs are giving me some grief. Viewing in File Explorer I can see the picture (in the thumbnail but not in "preview"). However, I can't do anything with it. I cannot open it in any program, I cannot copy it, move it, or even delete it. I am using an Administrator-level account.

It's pictures of my kids, so I want to salvage them if possible. What can I try?

This is Windows XP Professional (fully patched).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't know why I wasn't seeing the "Security" tab in file properties (as **joe** talks about in his answer) so I rebooted in safe mode. I was then able to see the Security tab.

Under Security, there was no user or group listed for any of the files that I was having trouble with, not even the generic "Everyone" group.

I added "Everyone" on the Advanced tab (needing to exit from Properties at least once) and set appropriate controls. Once done, everything worked as I expected.

I have no idea how the user permissions got so screwed up, but it's at least fixed and things working the way they should.

Answer (score 2):

Try to login with administrator user , mostly you can access and modify permisssion . The reason of no access is mostly that file might be handled by admin

For change the permission :

> Right click the folder you want to change permissions, go to properties --> security --> Advanced --> owner --> select your username and check "Replace owner on subcontainer and objects". Click OK --> OK. Most probably you'll be able to access your files now. Otherwise right the folder again, go to properties --> security and assign yourself full control.

Comment: Please note that I've already said that I'm using an admin account.

Comment: then that file is not access by admin user ;)

Comment: find out whether the user has permission to access that file ( edit , open )

Comment: However, I also noted that I'm not seeing the "security" tab. I rebooted in safe mode and checked those files again. This time I did have a security tab and there was NO permissions set, not even for "Everyone". So, I re-established ownership by the Administrator's group, rebooted, and now all is well.